# Uses of VC++ these days?

Tags: visual-c++

1. Can someone give examples of some good applications / project that are made in VC++ commercial and non-commercial.
2. What do you use VC++ for these(2008...) days ?
3. Do enterprise application three tier i.e get written in VC++
4. Is there any use in leaning MFC these days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer games are mostly still written in C++ on Windows using Visual Studio. Enterprise applications do usually use c# or java as enterprises have more money to buy hardware to make up for the difference in performance where games need to run on a significant amount of devices such as the PS3, Xbox 360, PS3, Windows, Mac etc. with limitations on memory.

Also embedded products, system utilities and software that makes extensive use of several low level API's are still written in C++. It definitely still has uses.

Comment: So all the games for PC's , XBOX, PS2 are written in C++ ya mean?

Comment: Anything that deals with high resolution data & high data rate in Windows is usually written in unmanaged code. Now VC++ (MFC) & ATL are unmanaged languages kinda well supported by Microsoft. eg. Games, Graphics , Plots etc are created in unmanaged code.

Comment: @abmv, not all games are written in C++, just most of them because it is the most portable language available. There are a lot of engines which allow developer to build cross-platform games using scripting languages like UnrealScript.

Answer (score 2):

For low-level stuff, there is still nothing that beats C and C++. For example, I wrote [Taekwindow](http://taekwindow.sf.net/) in Visual C++ 2008. It consists mostly of Windows API calls; any other language would be too much of a hassle, and in this case not even possible (hook procedures).

The configuration tool was done in C#, but I am currently redoing that in C++ to make code reuse easier. I did look at MFC briefly, but decided that I didn't like its bloat for such a simple program, so I ended up using only the vanilla Windows API and its dialog manager. Admittedly, I can be a bit of a masochist sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft said that they'll improve MSVC because they have customers who have millions of lines of C++ already. For all I know, *most* well-known, commercial applications for Windows, not to mention Windows itself, are built using MSVC: i.e. applications which have been years in the making.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent time I used MSVC (and MFC) was on a PocketPC/SmartPhone (i.e. Windows Mobile).

Answer (score 0):

The majority of cross platform computer games are always written in VC++ since abstractions are always used anyway. Some platforms such as PS3 even allow for games to be compiled straight out of VC for PS3.

I'd say, anything cross platform that has to run on both Windows, mac and/or linux has a high chance of being written in VC because it's the best IDE out there.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ is the ultimate programming tool which is still widely used in Most of the `Core Banking and financial products` developed by software companies. AS far as I know, `adobe products` are developed in `VC++` and if you want to code anything in `windows based pda or phones` , `vc++ embedded` which is also called `eVC++` is the way to go. Most of the kernel level `rootkits` are developed  making use of VC++ with DDK functionality. The list goes on like that. There is no reason to consider vc++ as being not used these days.